# Is possible to use black holes to propel a bullet or make a gun?

Tags: black-holes, kerr-metric

I was reading a book from my grandpa about Black Holes, and in one page it says that some objects can obtain some of the kinetic force from the black holes (in specific cases) and can propel themselves. Is possible to use this to propel a bullet or make a gun?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is known as "superradiance", i.e. the particle can extract energy from black hole. The particular effects, e.g. "Schwinger effect", "Penrose process" are all belong to this category.